# Emails not displaying in outlook 2010 - Shared mailbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have a shared mailbox where everyone can see 3 emails in a subfolder except for one user. All users are using exchange 2010 with cached exchange mode turned off. If I display the total count of emails in the folder on the affected users machine, it says 3, but the folder is empty. No view filters are enabled.

The user has full access permissions as per Microsoft exchange settings (Exchange 2010).

Any ideas why the user cannot see the 3 emails? She can see (almost) all other emails in the mailbox, but there are one or to other emails elsewhere that are missing too.

Edit: It's as if the emails are hidden because they are marked private, but the emails are not marked private.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a problem with exchange (I think!). After removing full access to the mailbox for the user and re-adding it again, the emails can now be seen.